# Getting file names in archive of an ArchiveInputStream

Tags: java, archive, apache-commons

Is there a way to get the just the filenames inside a archive with org.apache.commons ArchiveInputStream?

At the moment i'm using

```
while ((archiveEntry = archiveInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {    
  inputNames.add(archiveEntry.getName());
}
```

But to iterate over the whole stream when i just need the name of the files is very slow. Especially for large amounts of data .

Comment: How do you want to get the name of a archive, if you don't want to iterate over them in the first place? Or am I missing here something...

Comment: Depending on the archive format it might not be possible. For example tar does not have a directory tree in the archive, like for example ZIP. If you only need to deal with archive format which do store the directory tree, you might want to use some other tool. E.g. java.util.zip.ZipFile.

Comment: hmmm... Yes, i'm using tar archive format. Is there really no other way to get a list of the files inside the archive without to stream or skip over the whole archive. If i have a huge file inside the .tar file it takes really long.... :-((

Comment: No... `tar` was originally designed to allow appending additional files to the end of the archive.